# Prove that $\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$ is an Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $I=\left]-1,\ 1\right[$ be an interval, and $\left(I,\ \star\right)$ be a magma such that:

$$\left(\forall\  \left(x,\ y \right) \in I^2\right)\ x \star y=\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$$

I need to prove that $\left(I,\ \star\right)$ is an Abelian group.

A simple way to prove it is by checking that the magma $\left(I,\ \star\right)$ satisfies the group axioms including commutativity.

Based on the following statement I would like to approach that problem:

Let $f$ be a homomorphism from $\left(X,\ \perp \right)$ to $\left(I,\ \star\right)$, then the algebraic structure of $\left(I,\ \star\right)$ is exactly the algebraic structure of $\left(X,\ \perp \right)$

So I would like to find out a *usual* Abelian group - ex. $\left(\mathbb{R},\ +\right)$ - and a homomorphism $f$ from that group to $\left(I,\ \star\right)$.

Assume that $f$ is a homomorphism from $\left(X,\ \perp \right)$ to $\left(I,\ \star\right)$, then

$$\left(\forall\  \left(x,\ y \right) \in X^2\right)\ f\left(x \perp y \right)= f\left(x\right) \star f\left(y \right)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow f\left(x \perp y \right)= \frac{f\left(x\right) + f\left(y \right)}{1+f\left(x\right) \cdot f\left(y \right)}$$

I got stuck on that. Could anyone support me with some hints how to get it done.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $$\tanh (a+b)=\frac{\tanh a+\tanh b}{1+\tanh a\tanh b}.$$

Comment: Smart idea(+1), but it requires knowing that formula. Do you have any stepwise derivation schema?

Comment: @AyoubFalah It depends on what you *do* know. For example, if you know a similar formula for $\tan(a+b)$, you'd probably just check whether $\tanh(a+b)$ gives you what you want. If on the other hand you know enough special relativity for $\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$ to have arisen as a velocity addition, you'd probably try to parameterise $2\times 2$ Lorentz transformations. Alternatively, you might see whether $x\mapsto\frac{a+bx}{c+dx}$ simplifies your sum-and-product relation, and eventually you get interested in $\frac{\exp 2x-1}{\exp 2x+1}$.